# How many hairs per sq. cm. (or inch) do hamsters have on average?

Tags: zoology, hair

How many hairs per square centimeter (or inch) do common pet hamsters (*Mesocricetus auratus* or *Phodopus sungorus*) have on average?

I thought this would be easy to find by googling, but the best I've been able to find is [this 1986 article](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271007/1-s2.0-S0022202X00X00073/1-s2.0-S0022202X86901053/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjELv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIGY4hQN3hoL0Lr9Jo7QtJSqn%2FOlZLW3a8FE69Kul%2FLwqAiAbhjqmJtAmmRFH34HFeZ6bY%2B8h3umeRRWMsbdu6%2Fd%2F3Sq0AwhEEAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMaoYxNO69H1T6ALTEKpEDa16%2FTCg7Qar252SYLhbnS7DlGzVzGAKUb6veM3OutpEsDVrOw45vK2loiZG9x2IR%2FpNuNX46k5Km1KR7h7JYVtSgpnC89EttvMnaeD%2B4jIBMT%2BDAmSjKazbKYrsUC1nHJKexYS%2FdIBDlH7Zy%2F0AxlGjPbVw0t9Eq3odvz4%2B2r7gDe7SQ4TBW45F%2BKHndk45SrE5TjTD3qSnSJYH40UdJGEfA1EXmbDsIUWGofJrMmAW7cVGqpBzpE%2FQx%2FDJqstzQrpyE%2FxU4VVtfZ2y19p%2FfGBGxxp3ZgxwubIy7HiFtxw9il5pv2kENLYIE8W%2F39eWBzAQHx1Wistgf57w%2FbgvGDspCZ9RlrEc0fAYTQans%2BK%2FpVf7cmtmfTVnoFY4YmX%2Fn8P%2BEHzlg%2B36bs6%2BckQGAl7gobvEmhTjSSE2%2FEiH3kriWyUhrLj6YyUPfBhAdisz1iykHw%2FT2sb7dlt2Ou%2Fbs0IDTRJf3oYDDBYc9Zj4Eo1d3%2BfMkWsj9rxcxL5wodUA0neo9epCCPqrCFCLY6G1%2BqrcwpNGI%2FgU67AHDac357qnBIPWt3YE43giodY0ZH%2Bm78BYgKoxq0yu8QzM70nc5PFOYL%2BmnEMKnvP5L3ECbNDnlkOb0TxhvJjVHZ70zsb8iL71UR6wGTTBbu1qCIs4TuQYAYLm7A3NIPEraRmVbOEfpDATmFjK6jMhpD5Bh9X%2FEHhJWv0W9W0KHSd6DRhxPXe8kbyXaZD0Lz91H%2BaXVIOLTagvtOK9tZQWkwLP5N3GzBYpXSe1qVoo8mHllnHLFXep%2BRp8VDD9jhCiO8Zsma%2BE5qyhwMU%2BEXllIYF9k6F4zGR%2FmABXgAe3owWV%2BA7ydtHmzoyTUmg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201128T114455Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6LHK4HEU%2F20201128%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c597a07cf5375a53b7e90b89d1079ab865ececcde2470b02edc3f43452fb945b&hash=8ea45309bb5e4c2d05a7931848a2b2774ec48507060f05f9b4ebb471fbcd27da&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022202X86901053&tid=spdf-a08f7e0e-c552-4df7-92cb-88d22454e0f3&sid=516f849c25bb46424a082a25afe281d5dcaegxrqb&type=client), which isn't very clear in answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Paul et al. (2007)](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpregu.00520.2007), shaved fur patches of male Siberian and Syrian hamsters had a mass of about 12 mg/cm<sup>2</sup> dorsally and 3 mg/cm<sup>2</sup>  ventrally.

[This](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1572&bih=888&sxsrf=ALeKk01oYlP1_du36nIb9JRz4a16vO9kTg%3A1606564842717&ei=6jvCX_OuK4nSa__3oqgB&q=hamster%20%22hair%20density%22%20mm&oq=hamster%20%22hair%20density%22%20mm&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCCEQoAE6CggjEK4CELADECc6CAghEBYQHRAeUIwQWIoVYP8baABwAHgAgAGBAYgB0QOSAQMwLjSYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEBwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjzy4i2mKXtAhUJ6RoKHf-7CBU4ChDh1QMIDQ&uact=5) search give me the page.

[image: Fig 1, Paul et al. (2007)]

<sup>Fig 1 from Paul et al. (2007) compares mass of fur growth across time for 2 groups exposed to differing lengths of daylight (long, LD, and short, SD) to examine winter fur adaptation.</sup>

---

<sub>Paul, M.J., George, N.T., Zucker, I. and Butler, M.P., 2007. Photoperiodic and hormonal influences on fur density and regrowth in two hamster species. American Journal of Physiology-Regulatory, Integrative and Comparative Physiology, 293(6), pp.R2363-R2369.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like the results are in mass of hair per cm^2. It would help if I had data for what was the mass of 1 hair (or 1,000 hairs), but unfortunately, I don't have such data.

Comment: @Enivid calculating the mass of a single hair is less time consuming than counting all the hairs, and it's certainly something you could try yourself to add such info to this post. Any secondary or post-secondary school will have a balance that I'm sure they'd let you use. I'd recommend a digital model